# How do I add existing templates to Word 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

Word 2019 --- My attempts include:

1) Options -> Add-ins -> Manage: Templates -> Go -> place check on my templates

2) Options -> Advanced -> General -> File Locations -> User Templates -> Modify -> mouse to my templates.

When I run Word -> File -> New, I see no way to access my templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not recommended for you to modify your User Template folder. If you want load your custom templates in Word, I suggest you specify your personal template folder in Word Options:

[image]

You can click New and you'll see tabs labeled Office(FEATURED) and PERSONAL directly under the New label.

[image]

If you want to migrate your custom templates to User templates, please follow the method in [Where are my custom templates?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/where-are-my-custom-templates-88ed77ca-df34-49e9-9087-3f01ae296e6e)

Comment: Simple solution.  Thanks.